# Oracle Apex- Enter a value and convert it to a link

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a Master Detial with 2 interactive grids.
I would like to be able to genrate a link based on user input....is that at all possible?
To give a simple example:
Lets say I have website like https://www.google.com/
I would like a user to enter anything...for example "Prague"
Once this is entered, I would like APEX to generate a URL from it to result in: https://www.google.com/Prague

Now I know that Google search does not work like that, but I need that sort of mechanism for our internal company app. Is this possible?
Ideally , once the grid is saved the link in the Interactive grid only said "Prague" but if I click it, it would direct me to https://www.google.com/Prague

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using the "JavaScript Initialization Code" attribute of the column.
Example on the EMP sample table (*). Functionality is that when a user enters a value in the ENAME column, it is converted to a google search url.

1. Create an editable IG on table `EMP`
2. Set the type of column ENAME to "Text Field"
3. Set "Javascript Initialization Code" for column "ENAME" to

```
function(config) {     
    config.defaultGridColumnOptions = {         
        cellTemplate: '<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=&ENAME." target="_blank">&ENAME.</a>'     
    };     
    return config; 
}
```

Notice that the column now is a link. A user will have to open in new window to get the actual link value, since clicking the column will active the edit mode.

(*) Sample dataset can be installed using SQL Workshop > UTILITIES > Sample Data Sets > EMP/DEPT

Comment: Thank you so much! Its working great!
Have a great day, you made mine :)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can let user enter the value and by creating a dynamic action(choose the when attribute as whatever suits you)  you can take that value and on another column, use that column as &Columnvalue. for example and concatanate it by using to base url using ||